# How to intercept packet on TCP layer in kernel to analyze data?

Tags: linux, networking, tcp, linux-kernel

I intend to find certain packet data in the kernel and intercept it (either drop certain packets or redirect them). A natural way is to somehow catch all packets, inspect their data and drop/redirect certain packets.

I have tried to intercept them directly in the kernel code ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37490968/where-to-find-the-tcp-data-under-http-inside-linux-kernel?noredirect=1#comment62560765_37490968), at the [point](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/net/core/datagram.c?v=3.11#L319) to copy the data into user space) but the data that is pushed by the server without requests cannot be accessed there.

Another choice could be netfilter hooks like [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29553990/print-tcp-packet-data/29584449?noredirect=1#comment62629319_29584449). However, such hook is below TCP layer and it seems that reordering and packet losing is not dealt with yet.

So I'm wondering whether there are any elegant solutions to catch packet and operate on them upon TCP layer?

Thanks!

Comment: you could look at the snort IDS and write rules for that (or as it is open source, get the code, and work out what they do).

Comment: @Cwissy  Thanks! So may I ask one more question: do you know whether Snort works upon TCP (to handle reordering)? My gut feeling is that it could handle reordering because it uses libpcap which is used by tcpdump. Am I correct?

Comment: I don't, no, sorry.  I imagine it must do, however as I know you can write matching rules that get deep into the packets i.e. if an email comes from a certain address, drop packets from the ip address that is sending it.  Doing that would require opening each packet and there would be no point if it hadn't got the whole message in sequence.

Comment: @Cwissy  I see. OK let me go through the available Snort rules. Thank you so much for advising!

Comment: [wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) may help

Comment: All packets are below the transport layer (where TCP is). TCP datagrams are segments, not packets, which are layer-3 (e.g. IP) datagrams. If you are concerned about TCP reacting to lost data, you must intercept it above TCP. That is where the concept of client/server is. TCP is a per-to-peer protocol, and it knows nothing about clients or servers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to receive only specific stuff and drop not matching stuff, could you open a raw/tcp socket with a BFP filter attached to it ?

Ex - https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/filter.txt

Comment: This sounds a promising way! Two questions about it: 1) can I actually drop the packet to avoid it go into protocol stack? It seems that the filter can only drop packets for the current BFP socket. 2) Is there a easier way to write the magic filter code? The binary code is indeed not easy to handle.... Thanks!

Comment: 1. In your original question you mentioned not wanting to do netfilter because it is below TCP. On what basis do  you want to drop packets ? 2. This might be something you want to look at https://github.com/iovisor/bcc

Comment: You are right... The dilemma here is that BPF is under TCP and reordering/duplication is not handled yet... Thus it may not be easy to handle packets with content (which may separated in multiple packets).

Comment: No eBPF is at many places in the kernel. The BPF filter attached to socket via setsockopt SO_ATTACHFILTER is at socket layer which is ABOVE tcp layer. So that should work for you IIUC. The BCC thing I pasted is to show that you do not have to write BPF assembly to filter packets. You could use the BCC framework + compiler to attach filter at various places (including socket layer) and write filter code in C+Python.